# using datediff with 1 decimal for years

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which I have a column of types DATE for when a book has been published. I have a simple query which I would like to modify.

```
SELECT Books.title as Title, Books.release_date as Age FROM Books
```

The thing I would like modified is the return value of Books.release_date as Age, currently it is returning the DATE field which is in there (ex. 2005-2-5).

The value I would actually like to be seen selected out is the years it has been released as a decimal number (up to 1 decimal point), so it would show the age such as (ex. 8.2).

I believe that I will need to do something along the lines of

```
Select Books.title as Title, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Books.release_date)/365.25 as Age 
From Books
```

My results are showing up as 13.4949, which is to many decimal points, and also not sure if the dividing like that is the most accurate way?

Comment: Technically, it should use 365.2425 using the Gregorian calendar. Not that it would make much difference here...

Answer (score 2):

Division like what you are doing should work well to get the result you're looking for.

This should get you the right amount of decimal points:

```
Select Books.title as Title
, ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Books.release_date)/365.25,1) as Age 
From Books
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is useful

```
SELECT Books.title as Title, round(DATEDIFF(dd, '2005-2-5',getdate())/365.0,1) as Age FROM Books
```